# jQuery add class and remove all others

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have some nav anchors. I want to change some basic color schemes on the page when these are clicked. The only way I've been able to do this is with the code below.

It works fine, but I can't help but think there is a more elegant way. Does anybody know if it's possible to strip the classes in one foul swoop?

EDIT: This could have been more clear. I didn't want the original classes gone. Just the classes added with jQuery I guess. Sorry for the confusion.

Thanks.

EDIT: SEE [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/EXq83/)

Tried to implement all solutions.

getting an "{"error": "Please use POST request"}" though...

EDIT: this was because of href="?" vs. href="#" as pointed out.

```
    $(".home").click(function() {
        $(".primary-color").addClass("one");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("two"); 
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("three");   
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("four");    
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("five");           
    });

    $(".services").click(function() {
        $(".primary-color").addClass("two");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("one");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("three");   
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("four");    
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("five");       
    });

    $(".pricing").click(function() {
        $(".primary-color").addClass("three");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("one");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("two");     
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("four");    
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("five");       
    });

    $(".special-thing").click(function() {
        $(".primary-color").addClass("four");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("one");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("two"); 
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("three");   
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("five");   
    });

    $(".contact").click(function() {
        $(".primary-color").addClass("five");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("one");
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("two"); 
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("three");   
            $(".primary-color").removeClass("four");     
    });
```

Comment: FYI: http://jsfiddle.net is handy for quick tests to see if something works the way you need it to.

Comment: Yes. I am an avid user. I just wrote it all out an didn't save and refreshed. urg. took me a minute to get it written out again. And now with an error I've never seen. ? a

Comment: Dunno what browser you are using, but I've found that I understand Firebug console better than the console in chrome.

Comment: Firebug is what I am using. I find chrome more difficult. Although some people swear by it.

Comment: I can see it adding the classes. But they aren't being removed.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing it myself, but isolating your code is a good idea somethings. I.E. remove everything inside the click event except the `.removeClass()` and see if it removes the classes then. After that, just work your way up to the problem.. is something interrupting it ( error might indicate that.. ) or maybe you are undoing the removing of classes somehow.. or maybe the element you target is not found for some reason. `console.log()` is pretty handy for figuring out stuff. For example inside a click event: `console.log( $(this) )` tells you what the clicked element was...

Comment: Ok, noticed you fiddle there and here's the code from my answer ( bottom portion of my answer ) fitted into your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EXq83/5/ -- In your code, you remove all classes from an element and then try to target that element with a class that it doesn't have, since it was removed. Also, as a dummy `href=""` use `href="#"` instead of `?`.

Comment: Well... I used to use # - but then when using ajax that can be trouble and I heard from some people that ? was the safe bet... that's why I'm there...

Comment: Don't know about that, but jsfiddle doesn't seem to like the `?`. After it is replaced with `#`, the code works as it should ( as in the first click works properly, after that it fails the way I explained above ).

Comment: Well. You are correct about that hash in jsfiddle for sure. And your solution works and is a lot smaller. I don't totally get it - but that is my problem and I just have to spend some time with it. Thanks for your help. Solved the original issue and the new jsfiddle one.

Comment: Maybe this will clarify some things: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EXq83/14/

Comment: That was helpful. But because I use javaScript very rarely, things get out of hand fast. What is lost here, is that I have complicated underlying page styles that I don't want stripped. I think I blew it when I explained my question poorly. Learned a lot from this. Thank you.

Comment: Went to answer a similar question and found my question from 7 years ago! If I didn't use Vue / maybe Id do it like this now? https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/62retf7g/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do it this way

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ZUJUB/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".home, .services, .pricing, .special-thing, .contact").on("click", function() {

        $(".primary-color")
            // Remove all classes
            .removeClass()
            // Put back .primary-color class + the clicked elements class with the added prefix "pm_".
            .addClass('primary-color pm_' + $(this).attr('class') );       
    });
});​
```

CSS:

```
.primary-color {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;

}


.pm_services { background: red; }
.pm_home { background: green; }
​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="services">services</div>
<div class="home">home</div>

<div class="primary-color">Primary-color</div>
​
```

---

---

or something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ZUJUB/1/

This fitted into the OP's structure: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EXq83/5/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttons > div").on("click", function() {

        $(".primary-color")
            // Remove all classes
            .removeClass()
            // Put back .primary-color class + the clicked elements index with the added prefix "pm_".
            .addClass('primary-color pm_' + ( $(this).index() + 1 ) );       
    });
});​
```

CSS:

```
.primary-color {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;

}


.pm_1 { background: red; }
.pm_2 { background: green; }
​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div class="services">services</div>
    <div class="home">home</div>
</div>

<div class="primary-color">Primary-color</div>
​
```

Comment: Since the index of the parent li is used, you can add and remove menu items without the need to touch the javascript. Also, you might want to add `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the link from firing on click. http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EXq83/17/ ( Notice the e inside the click events brackets at the top )

Answer (score 6):

You cans use attr method,

```
$(".xxx").attr("class","newclass");
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer above others becuase i was using the Mutation Observer to check for changes to the `class` attribute of an element and it was triggering twice which i noticed was using the similar approach as other answers are added means using 2 calls `.addCLass().removeClass()` and i needed to change them to a single call and using `.attr()` solved my problem

Answer (score 6):

Just `$(".primary-color").removeClass()` (without specifying the class) should work!

Or, if you just need to strip the classes (leaving other, important classes), you can group it into 1 call, separating the classes by spaces:

```
$(".primary-color").removeClass("two three four five");
```

Comment: Ooooh, does this work?! **edit:** Just tried it, yep it does!

Comment: This one is great. Still have to write them out, which depending on the scope, could be hard to scale. But cuts my lines to 10%. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `removeClass()` without parameter to remove all classes
see: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

```
$(".primary-color").removeClass();
```

or use space-separated notation to remove your specified classes:

```
$(".primary-color").removeClass('one two');
```

or set completely new class attribute by `attr()`:

```
$(".primary-color").attr('class','one two');
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$(".home").click(function() {
   $(".primary-color").removeClass().addClass("one");          
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can remove all classes from an element by doing

```
$("#item").removeClass();
```

Calling removeClass with no parameters will remove all of the item's classes.

Do this before you do `addClass` and your code will be reduced

Comment: No go on that. I'm watching it in firebug and it's just adding classes until they are all there and then it just ends and gets stuck. Sounded like it would be a sweet trick. Any thing I might have done wrong? I just have the on-click - remove - and then add.

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle in the question. One of the events uses this code. It definitely removes all of the classes. I have initial classes that I don't want to strip though. It seems to just go dead.

Comment: you can remove a set of classes by using multiple parameters when you call the remove class function --> .removeClass('one two');

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.  Rather than add and subtract, you should simply set the class attribute.  Granted, if there are classes you which to retain, you can set those as well, but if that isn't suitable, you should probably consider doing it in another way entirely.

```
$(".home").click(function() {
    $(".primary-color").attr("class", "one");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of contractiosn can be applied. Without knowing the specifics of your code, it's difficult to make any further changes.

```
$(".home, .contact, .special-thing, .pricing, .services").click(function() {
  $(".primary-color")
    .addClass("one")
    .removeClass("two three four five");          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

8 years later...

I think I'd use a data-attribute - and then just switch it out, vs. adding and removing classes.

`<body data-theme='punk'>` or something.

https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/34c8b5540b34c8ee9aedec604bbd5f59 & you can use the browsers localStorage to save the selection too : )

```js
// I'd use body... but for this
var context = document.querySelector('main');

function setTheme(name) {
  context.dataset.theme = name;
}

setTheme('default');


// https://gomakethings.com/why-is-javascript-event-delegation-better-than-attaching-events-to-each-element/
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  
  setTheme(event.target.dataset.themeOption);
  
});
```

```css
main[data-theme='default'] {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

main[data-theme='punk'] {
  background-color: #FF0066;
}

main[data-theme='corperate'] {
  background-color: white;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<main data-theme='default'>

  <button data-theme-option='default'>Default</button>
  <button data-theme-option='punk'>Punk</button>
  <button data-theme-option='corperate'>Corperate</button>

  <h1>Theme changer thingy</h1>

</main>
```